# Unable to nuget restore after changing target framework from .NetStandard 2.0 to .net 4.7.2

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard, nuget-package-restore, .net-framework-version

I've just updated several of our projects from .net framework 4.6.2 to .net framework 4.7.2 and I'm getting the following errors:

```
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.2 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.2 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.1 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 (win7-x86).
```

What really confuses me with this is that .NETFramework 4.7.2 is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 so why are we getting this error message?  It doesn't make sense!
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey -- which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Locally I've got VS2017 15.7.5 where it works but the hosted VSTS VS2017 build agent has VS 2017 15.7.4. I'll try downgrading locally to see if it fails locally (it currently runs locally) but this feels like a nuget issue specifically

Comment: It looks like the VSTS hosted service is using nuget v4.1.0 but locally I'm using V4.6.0.  Feels like this could be the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on our CI server, turned out an older copy of `nuget.exe` was installed, upgrading that to the latest fixed the issue (v4.1 to 4.7)

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me in AzureDevOps known as VSTS :

1 - Add a dotnet restore step.

2 - In the advanced options of the Nuget Restore step, select the Custom version and set the "Path to Nuget.exe" as : $(Build.BinariesDirectory)\nuget.exe

3 - Before the NuGet restore Task add an Inline PowerScript shell, Refer to this github link : 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3756#issuecomment-288185011

Don't forget to change the version of nuget in the Shell Script to the one you want ( for me it's the 4.3.0).

Comment: Use the nuget-tool-installer task instead of the inline powershell, thats the correct way to do this. important note: 4.3 or above is required as nuget version because that is when nuget.exe was introduced to netstandard/netframework-compatiblity

Answer (score -3):

Update your NuGet installer to version 2.*. After that NuGet.exe will auto-update to version 4.3

Comment: This has [already been said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340237/542251), no need to add another answer re-iterating the same point